# TypeError: Redirected path should match configured path, but got: /callback

Tags: firebase, express, oauth-2.0, google-cloud-functions, quickbooks

I have deployed the ExpressJs app on firebase function and trying to trigger the express app with an HTTP trigger.

I am trying to authorize my express app with OAUTH2.0 to use QuickBooks API. However, I am getting the following error:

```
TypeError: Redirected path should match configured path, but got: /callback
    at CodeFlow.getToken (/srv/node_modules/client-oauth2/src/client-oauth2.js:597:7)
    at /srv/routes/callback.js:12:25
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/srv/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at next (/srv/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:137:13)
    at Route.dispatch (/srv/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:112:3)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/srv/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at /srv/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:281:22
    at Function.process_params (/srv/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:335:12)
    at next (/srv/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:275:10)
    at Function.handle (/srv/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:174:3)
```

The error is in following file:
callback.js

```
router.get('/', function (req, res) {
  // Verify anti-forgery

  console.log("OriginalURL "+req.originalUrl)
  console.log("base URL "+req.baseUrl)
  // Exchange auth code for access token
  tools.intuitAuth.code.getToken(req.originalUrl).then(function (token) {  //This is where promise is failing
```

I am using npm package called "client-oauth2".
client-oauth2.js

```
if (
    typeof options.redirectUri === 'string' &&
    typeof url.pathname === 'string' &&
    url.pathname !== Url.parse(options.redirectUri).pathname
  ) {
    return Promise.reject(
      new TypeError('Redirected path should match configured path, but got: ' + url.pathname)  //The source of Error. I am not able to find out the value of options.redirectUri
    )
  }
```

Following are my configuration details:

```
"redirectUri": "us-central1-thematic-runner-245505.cloudfunctions.net/createEstimate/callback"
```

I have made sure that this URL matches with Quickbooks side redirect URL. In the case of **localhost** it works just fine.

```
Localhost URL: http://localhost:5001/thematic-runner-245505/us-central1/createEstimate/
```

The value of req.originalUrl from callback.js is

```
OriginalURL /thematic-runner-245505/us-central1/createEstimate/callback?code=AB11585447829JwgpXMEpWOR6irwprMe9Z8aqRoSK4npFDKmte&state=Z0t9yRkl-dWaO2J5sJRDaTB9eZKvyyyVcHYQ&realmId=4620816365002391850
```

Could somebody help me with this error? I don't know what I am doing wrong in the case of production. The callback URL seems to be fine. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a valid URL:

```
"redirectUri": "us-central1-thematic-runner-245505.cloudfunctions.net/createEstimate/callback"
```

There's no `scheme/protocol` portion to that URL (e.g. `https://`). It should start with `https://` but instead you're jumping right into the domain.

It needs to be a valid URL, including the protocol/scheme.